# Parsing s-expression structure into tree and summing the paths

Tags: python, beginner

I'm new to Python, just attempted the task [here](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps100/fall03/assign/extra/treesum.html).

The part I found hardest was parsing the expression into the tree structure. I was originally trying to build a regular tree structure (i.e. a Node object with left and right nodes), but without any logic for the insertion (i.e. newNode < node then insert left, newNode > node then insert right) I couldn't find a way.

In the end I've used Python's lists to kind of replicate the expression structure, and walk the paths as they're created. Each time I find a leaf, I calculate the cumulative sum, pop the last added node, and carry on.

The one part of the code I really don't like is the way I'm finding leafs:

```
if tree and expression[i-1:i+3] == ['(',')','(',')']:
```

and I don't like that I've done:

```
pair[1].replace('(', ' ( ').replace(')', ' ) ').split()
```

twice.

Any guidance on any part of this - style or just general approach and logic would be great.

```
def pairs(value):
    """ Yields pairs (target, expression) """
    nest_level = 0
    expr = ""
    target = 0

    value = value.replace('(', ' ( ').replace(')', ' ) ').split()
    for x in value:
        if x.isdigit() and not expr:
            target = x
        else:
            expr += x

        if x is '(':
            nest_level += 1
        elif x is ')':
            nest_level -= 1
            if nest_level is 0:
                yield target, expr
                expr = ''
                target = 0


def main():
    with open('input') as f:
        expr_input = f.read()

        level = 0
        current_target = 0

        for pair in pairs(expr_input):
            current_target = pair[0]
            # stack representing the 'current path'
            tree = list()
            # store the cumulative total of each path for this expression
            cumulative_totals = list()
            running_total = 0

            expression = pair[1].replace('(', ' ( ').replace(')', ' ) ').split()
            for i, s in enumerate(expression):
                if s is '(':
                    level += 1
                elif s == ')':
                    level -= 1
                    # "is leaf?" ugh.
                    if tree and expression[i-1:i+3] == ['(',')','(',')']:
                        cumulative_totals.append(running_total)
                        # remove the node and carry on down the next path
                        node = tree.pop()
                        running_total = running_total - int(node)
                    if level is 0:
                        if int(current_target) in cumulative_totals:
                            print "yes"
                        else:
                            print "no"
                else:
                    running_total += int(s)
                    tree.append(s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

1. **Avoid indentation**.

   ```
                           print "no"
   ```

   When you need this amount of spaces in front of your code, I'd say *no* too.

   This is clearly a sign that what you're writing could be extracted into a function call, our main could be a chain of function calls instead of a big clump of code.

   ```
   with open('input') as f:
       parseFile(f)

   def parseFile(...):
       ...
       for pair in pairs(expr_input): parsePair(pair)
       ...

   def parsePair(...):
       ...
       for i, s in enumerate(expression): addExpressionToSummation(i, s)
       ...
   ```

   Of course, this won't work out of the box; that's what object-oriented programming will help with.

   Also, if you need to map one-to-one, use list comprehensions or functions like `map`.
2. **Regular expressions might sometimes be valuable**.

   ```
   value = value.replace('(', ' ( ').replace(')', ' ) ').split()
   ```

   can be

   ```
   value = re.sub(r'(\(|\))', r' \1 ', value).split();
   ```

   which can be improved to not add multiple spaces by restricting the match or by doing another replace where you replace `r' +'` by `r' '`. Of course this example might not be worth it, but if you've got to do heavier duty then you'll quickly want to resort to a regular expression instead of much longer trial-and-error code.
3. **Conditions can be functions, too.**

   ```
   # "is leaf?" ugh.
   if tree and expression[i-1:i+3] == ['(',')','(',')']:
   ```

   Imagine that'd be

   ```
   if isLeaf(tree, expression):
   ```

   Oh look, our documentation line is gone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not per-ce what you asked, but code can be split into two distinct steps:

1. Parse the given string to some data structure.
2. Execute algorithm on that structure.

Step [1] can be done in 3 lines, as the string is almost a python syntax as is:

```
s = '(5 (4 (11 (7 () ()) (2 () ()) ) ()) (8 (13 () ()) (4 () (1 () ()) ) ) )'
s = s.replace('(',',[')
s = s.replace(')',']')
s = s[1:]
```

Now `s` is a valid python list:

```
'[5 ,[4 ,[11 ,[7 ,[] ,[]] ,[2 ,[] ,[]] ] ,[]] ,[8 ,[13 ,[] ,[]] ,[4 ,[] ,[1 ,[] ,[]] ] ] ]'
```

Let's put it into a variable:

```
ltree = eval(s)
```

Now `ltree` is a good tree representation - it is in fact a DFS walk on the tree.

`ltree[0]` is the root value, `ltree[1]` is the left subtree, and `ltree[2]` is the right subtree - and so on.

And the code to test the walk becomes simple:

```
def is_sum(tree, num):
   if (len(tree) == 0):   # 'in' a leaf
      return False
   if (len(tree[1]) == 0 & len(tree[2]) == 0):   # leaf
      return num == tree[0]
   return (is_sum(tree[1], num-tree[0]) | is_sum(tree[2], num-tree[0]))
```